# How to change button text when clicked?

Tags: javascript, function

I am running my website off of squarespace and I have a button that says "DELIVER ME" but when you click it, I want it to say "G.T.F.O" while the next page loads.

I don't have a code for this and need help writing one.

```
function changeButtonText(DELIVER ME, G.T.F.O.){
    if (this.value== "DELIVER ME"){
     this.value = "G.T.F.O.";
    } else {
     this.value = "DELIVER ME";
   }
}

changeButtonText();
```

I want the button to say "DELIVER ME" until you click it, then once you click it the button will say "G.T.F.O."

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeText() {
  return document.querySelector("#button").innerHTML = "New text";
}

document.addEventListener("click", changeText);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">Text</button>
```

Comment: This will change the text of the first button on the page, which might not be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the button to say "DELIVER ME" until you click it, then once you click it the button will say "G.T.F.O."

Given this button:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="DELIVER ME">
```

You could do it like this:

```
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.value = "G.T.F.O."
});
```

Or, if the button is like this:

```
<button id="myButton">DELIVER ME</button>
```

You would do:

```
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
myButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.innerText = "G.T.F.O."
});
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the answer can solve your particular problem but I just want to add more information about selecting htmlElement.

in VanillaJS(pure Javascript) DOM. you can select element with 3 DOM method.

1. Select by ID's attribute

   `elem = document.getElementById("id")`
2. Select by class attribute

   `elem = document.getElementsByClassName("class")`
3. Select by TagName

   `elem = document.getElementByTagName("Tag")`

and 1 more extra way which used.

```
elem = document.querySelector(selector)
```

selector can be one of ".class","#id", or "Tags"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick=changeButtonText()>deliver me</button>
```

```
<script>

    function changeButtonText(){
    document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "GTFO";             
    }                       

</script>
```