# How do I change the background color on this code

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change the color on the background of this button to a dark red. 
I also need the text to change when you hover over the button. I want it to say G.F.Y.T.S. when you hover over the button.

The code below is what I've tried:

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Roger George Expendables"/>
```

Comment: Nothing in that code has anything to do with background color. You want a `:hover` CSS rule, for starters. You were [already told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223254/how-to-change-button-text-when-clicked) how to change the button text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a stylesheet or inline styles in the HTML code. From there, you can say something like this:

```
.button {
    background: #8b0000
}
```

Next, you want a hover selector. This means you need to do something like this:

```
.button:hover {
    background: <hexvaluehere>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css class for the button and add background color and text-color un the class. Add :hover for the class over.

Answer (score 0):

tree ways

1. Adding inline definition of your style

http://google.com';" value="Roger George Expendables"/>

2. Adding a style section to your HTML and defining a class

   .myClass{
     background-color:yellow
   }

   http://google.com';" value="Roger George Expendables"/>
3. Adding a reference to a style sheet in your code